# Scrapy pagination timing error

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

So I set up a spider very similarly to the example on scrapy.

I want the spider to crawl all of the quotes BEFORE going to the next page. I also want it to parse only 1 quote per second. So if there were 20 quotes on a page, it would take 20 seconds to scrape the quotes then 1 second to go to the next page.

As of right now, my current implementation is iterating through each page first before actually getting the quote information.

```
import scrapy

class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'author'

start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    # follow links to author pages
    for href in response.css('.author+a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                             callback=self.parse_author)

    # follow pagination links
    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

    yield {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }
```

Here are the basics of my settings.py file

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could orchestrate how the scrapy.Requests are yielded.

For example, you could create the next page Request, but only yield it when all authors Requests terminate scraping its items.

Example:

```
import scrapy

# Store common info about pending request
pending_authors = {}

class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'author'

start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self, response):

    # process pagination links
    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    next_page_request = None
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        # Create the Request object, but does not yield it now
        next_page_request = scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # Requests scrapping of authors, and pass reference to the Request for next page
    for href in response.css('.author+a::attr(href)').extract():
        pending_authors[href] = False  # Marks this author as 'not processed'
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_author,
                             meta={'next_page_request': next_page_request})


def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

    item = {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }

    # marks this author as 'processed'
    pending_authors[response.url] = True

    # checks if finished processing of all authors
    if len([value for key, value in pending_authors.iteritems() if value == False]) == 0:
        yield item
        next_page_request = response.meta['next_page_request']

        # Requests next page, after finishinr all authors
        yield next_page_request
    else:
        yield item
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Global name `pending_authors` is not defined.

Comment: JK it should be self.pending_authors for all instances of it.

Comment: Follow up question: I noticed that with this method, it will not attempt to go to the next link if it sees an already-parsed page. Do you know how to disable this (do not scrape authors it has seen before, but still iterate through the pages)?

Comment: Just edited my answer, 'pending_authors' is meant to be global, not for each instance. About the follow up question: this is just an example of what you could do to orchestrate the scraping request; you could save the authors by something else than the url. I've done something similar to this, but I used mongodb to store the items, and as I scraped I could check first before saving the scraped data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I noticed a few things with this implementation.

1. pending_authors has to be called globally in parse and parse_author
2. With this implementation, if you see a duplicate author (one that you parsed before in a previous scrape), it will not be handled unless you set the key in the global pending_authors dict to true in middleware.py